# How to define PIVOT table source dynamically?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a PIVOT table from different worksheets and insert each PIVOT output in a certain column into a table.

```
Sub PivotvpcodeSATURATION()
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("24.11.")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("25.11.")
Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("26.11.")
Set ws4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("27.11.")
Set ws5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("28.11.")
Set ws6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("29.11.")
Set ws7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("30.11.")
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add

i = 3
z = 16

Do
ws1.Select
Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "24.11.!R1C2:R11754C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14

    wsNew.Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("VP CODE")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    wsNew.Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable").PivotFields("1/0"), "Sum of 1/0", xlSum

 wsNew.Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("VP_Saturation").Select

   ' Range(Cells(3, z).Address).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsNew.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    z = z + 2
Loop Until z = 28
End Sub
```

The thing i am non able to reach is,

how to define a worksheets name as a variable, so that i don't have to select **w1, w2,w.., wn** each time, and don't have to put a sheet name inside **24.11.!R1C2:R11754C10** .

As well the column name where to insert copied Pivot result i define as a variable **Cells(3, z).Address.Select**, but this string returns an error.

Maybe someone can help with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all worksheets in an array and do a cycle on each element of the array with `For Each....Next`

regarding your second question, change:
   `SourceData:="24.11.!R1C2:R11754C10"`
to
   `SourceData:=ws1.name&"!R1C2:R11754C10"`
and it will feed the worksheet name into the string

third question:
replace
 `Range(Cells(3, z).Address).Select`
with
`Cells(3, z).Select`

Comment: Thanks, it helped. The only thing that i could not manage in which sequence to do a loop? If i say: `For Each DayWeek2 In Week2 Do ... z = z + 2 Next DayWeek2 Loop Until z = 29` It gives an error

Comment: Your `next` and `loop until` are wrong way around, loops have to be within each other, I.e. `Do` is inside `for` so `loop until` must be inside too,  before `next`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a template Excel file where the format doesn't change.  I suggest creating a dynamic named range for all your data sources.  Then just go to each pivot table and refer to the named range in Change Source Pivot Table Options.
All your VBA has to do is a variation of ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll.

Use a variation of this formula to create the dynamic named range: =Data!$A$5:OFFSET(Data!$A$5,COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1,52).  Basically choose the data source sheet, the starting cell, and how many columns over the data sits.  The rows will adjust automatically.